# Hosted MVC3 app, only directory listing. Routing not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Ok so deploying to local IIS my project works fine. Deploying to the online host, I only get directory listing.

(

Using VisualStudio 2012, mvc3, .net 4.5
Publish to Web settings:

1. Publish method: FTP
2. Server: `www."mysite".co.za`
3. Site Path: "blank"   (My understanding is that I'm publishing directly to the app directory, so my root contains bin, views, global.asax, web.config)
4. Destination URL: `http://www."mysite".co.za`
5. Databases are already up and configured in web.config

)

If click on the Views directory I get the 404 error.

What I did next was to see if it executes global.asax, so I added code to throw an exception in RegisterRoutes (Called from Application_Start())

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {      
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults        
      );

      throw new Exception("This is my custom error: Currently in RegisterRoutes");      
    }
```

And true's Bob, I get the following (**but still only if I click on my View directory**):

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
 This is my custom error: Currently in RegisterRoutes 
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
 Exception Details: System.Exception: This is my custom error: Currently in RegisterRoutes
```

So my questions:
 1. Why would my root not pick up global.asax?
 2. How can I see where execution of code ends after routes.MapRoute(...)? (that is, after removing the throw Exception ;) )

Regards

Comment: What action/endpoint is your View directory executing?

Comment: It's the normal View directory used by the mvc framework. Not an action for any controller.

Comment: @E.Venter: Did you try my solution? Let me know weather it worked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to be as well.  Usually this is due to some missing settings in the web config.  Specifically, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601325/asp-net-mvc3-in-iis-7-5), provided the answer.  Edit the web config to load all managed modules for all requests.

```
<system.webServer><modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules></system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After 3days of trial and error it is finally up and running!

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't register IIS on your server. Please register it using `aspnet_regiis -i` and then check the .net version under application pool in IIS.