# HTTP Error 404.3-Not Found in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, mime-types

I'm using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise Edition. In the project we have developed with ASP.NET 4.0 we used WCF Service. But it doesn't run over domain when the software is running from local computer. Otherwise, I am getting the following error:

> **HTTP Error 404.3-Not Found**
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension
>   configuration. If the page is script, add a handler. If the file should
>   be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You should install IIS sub components from

`Control Panel` -> `Programs and Features` -> `Turn Windows features on or off`

`Internet Information Services` has subsection `World Wide Web Services` / `Application Development Features`

There you must check `ASP.NET` (`.NET Extensibility`, `ISAPI Extensions`, `ISAPI Filters` will be selected automatically). Double check that specific versions are checked. Under Windows Server 2012 R2, these options are split into 4 & 4.5.

Run from `cmd`:

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`

Finally check in IIS manager, that your application uses application pool with .NET framework version v4.0.

Also, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5).

Comment: Mine had everything selected and .NET v4.0.  Didn't work. (Sad Panda)

Comment: @obesechicken13, open `inetmgr` (`win+R`)
1. Check that you have .NET ApplicationPools with a proper version (`aspnet_regiis` creates it).
2. Find your Site/Application under `Sites` and in `Basic Settings` check which Application Pool is chosen.

Comment: After clicking "Turn Windows features on or off" it's extremely unclear where I should go next. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Very helpful answer, I am struggling to find out the solution from yesterday evening, at-last this `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` this does the trick

Comment: For Windows 10 running "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir" had no effect, it said that I shall do the ASP.NET installation via IIS (which was first step) and that no changes were made to existing web applications to use this version of ASP.Net. But still IT WORKED.

Comment: Even though I had installed the .NET Framework version that was newer than what is installed using the Roles and Features, I still had to tick that box before everything would work.

Answer (score 33):

In my case, along with Mekanik's suggestions, I was receiving this error in Windows Server 2012 and I had to tick "HTTP Activation" in "Add Role Services".

Comment: More reference can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh167503(v=nav.70).aspx

Comment: What program were you running that gave you the option to add role services?

Comment: I had to do this with windows 8.1.

Comment: Solved same issue in Windows 10. Windows features > .NET Framework > WCF-services.

Comment: Worked prefectly after activating "HTTP Activation"

Answer (score 5):

In windows server 2012, even after installing asp.net you might run into this issue.

Check for "Http activation" feature. This feature is present under Web services as well.

Make sure you add the above and everything should be awesome for you !!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble accessing wcf service hosted locally in IIS. Running aspnet_regiis.exe -i wasn't working.

However, I fortunately came across the following:

[Rahul's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjohri/archive/2009/06/29/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configuration.aspx)

which informs that servicemodelreg also needs to be run:

Run Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt as “Administrator”.
Navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation.
Run this command servicemodelreg –i.