# HTTP Error 404.3 in iis

Tags: http, iis, iis-7.5

I'm trying to access my site but it's showing an error message HTTP Error 404.3.

Error-Message

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it and proud to post it's Solution.To resolve it Please Follow these steps.

```
 Go To  Control panel->Turn Window feature's ON or Off ->Internet Information 
Service->World Wide Web Services ->Application Development Features -> Check the ASP and 
click on OK .
```

Now Reload Your Page and have a look. Your Issue Have Been Resolved. Please see the given image for more understanding.[image: How we resolve HTTP error 404.3 in IIS]

Answer (score -2):

Did you google around on this?
Here is the solution on Stackoverflow itself

[HTTP Error 404.3-Not Found in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425442/http-error-404-3-not-found-in-iis-7-5)

Main url:

[ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)