# The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

**HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found  The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
I am new to IIS and ASP.net .**

1. I developed an application in asp.net 4.0 using c#. ( on my laptop)
2. I Published the website in File System . ( on my laptop)
3. I installed 'IIS 8 Web Server' on 'windows Server 2012 R2' by using windows add feature option.
4. I copied the website published folder on Windows Server 2012 R2 from my laptop.
5. I created an Application pool on IIS.
6. I added a new website and created its virtual directory.
7. Added the home.aspx page in the default Documents.

and Now I am getting this error which I am unable to debug . Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 404.3 in iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458059/http-error-404-3-in-iis)

Comment: Do read an official guide before moving on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules#installing-iis-and-aspnet-modules

Answer (score 0):

It depend on what extension are you requesting for.  IIS return 404.3 when either there is no handler could handle the request or the extension is not included in mime type.

1.Please ensure asp.net and extension feature has been installed from turn windows features on or off.

2.If you get 404.3 when you request static file, please remember to register mimetype for it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap