# Changing server address in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

when I compile my project it runs in the url http://localhost:12421/index.html

Can I run it in my private ip? lets say http://192.168.1.212:12421/index.html
I tried to browse that and it gave me error
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example I have an `ASP.NET` project by name **myWebSite**.
The below ways to change the `http://localhost:12421/` **server address** to a **IP** address for e.g:  `192.168.1.7:80` always worked for me.

1. [Enable IISExpress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx) on your computer

[image: Windows Features]

2. [Add a NetShare Reservation](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express)
   Open your Command Line (**CMD**) **Run As Administrator** in Windows and go to `c:\Windows\system32>`, then type:
    
   `netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.7:80/ user=everyone`
   and then press `Enter` key. 
   You should be seen a `URL reservation successfully added` message.

[image: CMD]

3. Go to `C:/Users/UserName/Documents/IISExpress/config/` and open `applicationhost.config`.
   In the `applicationhost.config` file find your site in the `<sites>` section.
   Example:

```xml
<sites>
    <site name="myWebSit" id="1">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\myWebSit\myWebSit" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12421:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
</sites>
```

Now change address to your IP instead `localhost`. For e.g:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:192.168.1.7" />
```

4. Change Project Url to own address
   Open your project on Visual Studio; Right click on your start up project and select `properties`.
   In the properties select `Web` tab and then change **Project Url** text box contents to your address. For e.g: `http://192.168.1.7:80/` and click on `Create Virtual Directory` button. 
   You should be seen a `The virtual directory was created successfully.` message.

[image: VSWebTab]

Now, you should be able to run your project in Visual Studio by own IP address.

[Reference](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1486251)

Answer (score 2):

From where are you trying to access? The machine from where you're trying to access must be in the same network, if it is check that you are not blocking the connection on the Firewall (possibly the windows' firewall).
Are you using IIS or IIS Express? If you're using IIS Express you'll need to to edit applicationhost.config file manually and change bindingInformation '::'.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you run asp.net app from visual studio, it runs from the asp.net development server installed. so, it will run in localhost:port. But if you want to run using ip address then you have to use iisexpress and give port number with ip address in vs project->properties->web. follow the steps as follows given in the address: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1486251

Are you trying to browse your app after deploying on IIS?
To browse using ip address on IIS check out as follows:

1. check if you can ping the server pc by pinging ip in command prompt.
2. check if firewall is blocking. if so turn your firewall off.
3. go to application pool after deploying on IIS
4. select your application inside pool and select binding
5. bind to your ip address and give a port number that is not occupied.

Thanks

Comment: In visual studio under properties>Web. It says unable to create virtual directory. You must specify localhost for the server name.

Comment: do you want to run in visual studio with ip address?

Comment: i was performing the last step on that url https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1486251  Anyway, my apppool only shows defaultAppPool. Is it correct? under Sites: There is only Default Web Site

Comment: no under application pool there has to be a pool of your published copy. ex. if you publish your app named as 'abc',  then inside application pool there has to be 'abc' and it's status has to be started. s

Comment: but except visual studio if you want to browse using ip after publishing in iis then select the published file in iis, select binding. and in the sit binding dialogue give ip address and port number that is not used elsewhere.

Comment: Ok this is what i did so far. Right click project in VS and publish to inetpub/wwwroot folder. Then i open IIS Manager> Add website>Sitename="testing"> Application Pool= DefaultAppPool >Physical  Path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" >Binding is http:\\192.168.1.212:80, hostname i left it blank

Comment: I then added Default Document>index.aspx. When i try to browse it i get HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found. Then i manually went to the folder and open it and i get "This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name"

Comment: These are my starting code. <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: publish your application in a folder. then copy the folder and paste into inetpub->wwwroot folder. right click on the folder and convert it to application. select your application and go to binding. give ip and port number.

Comment: Thanks i found the mistake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425442/http-error-404-3-not-found-in-iis-7-5