# Can't open Visual studio asp.net project using local IIS server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm new to this asp.net framework. I wanted to deploy my application to Local IIS server. I even created virtual Directory successfully. There is no error. But when i run the project it always saying

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Login page is .aspx file. After I created sample html file and run it. The sample html file deployed to the IIS without causing any problem. Can anybody please tell me the reason. Is It some kind of File Extension Problem

Answer (score 0):

**here are your answers:**

[HTTP Error 404.3-Not Found in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425442/http-error-404-3-not-found-in-iis-7-5#answer-8487214)

[ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5#answer-2376484)

Comment: It was very helpful.And it worked fine..thank you..!!