# HTTP Error 404.3-Not Found in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I use IIS version 10 and Windows 10 and VisualStudio 2015.

After I add WEB application  to IIS site and open it I get error:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

I installed IIS sub components from:

```
Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off
```

As described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425442/http-error-404-3-not-found-in-iis-7-5) by Mekanik.

Here is screenshot of installed sub components:

[image]

But it didn't helped me and still I get the same error.

Any Idea why I keep getting this error above maybe it has something to do with version of `IIS 10`?

Answer (score 22):

I understand that this is an old issue but in case anyone else comes across it:

It is related to Handler mapping, you need the *svc-integrated* mapping for the site in question:

[Handler mapping in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBC7w.png)

In order to make sure this mapping appears you need to go to **control panel** -> **turn windows features on or off** -> **.NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services (or equiv .net ver)** -> **WCF Services** -> **HTTP Activation**

Turn on Http Activation and refresh IIS. This should add the mapping and fix the error.

[Http Activation Feature Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMCG6.png)

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem for a WCF web service.
Fixed it as follows:
Open - Turn Windows Features ON or OFF, then 
Enable HTTP Activation

Answer (score 1):

What kind of application are you browsing ? Based on the extension make sure you have proper handler mapping i.e. IIS Manager => Sites => specific site => Handler mappings

Another thing is in IIS Manager Select the Server (above Application Pools) double click on ISAPI and CGI Restrictions and see if everything is allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

For me, lots of Handler Mappings were missing from the Default Website in IIS.
In IIS, click your server, then click Handler Mappings and see what you have. After that, click your website and check Handler Mappings there. If many are missing, this is probably the problem.

I right-clicked in the Handler Mappings page and picked Revert to parent. Note that if you have changes here, these will be lost.