# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Error when starting debug in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2017

I have set up project to be run on IIS for some time ago and when I did press F5 it did connect no problem. But recently this stopped working and I did get this error when I press F5 / press `Debug->Start debugging`:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not Found.

[image]

Here is my settings:

[image]

I am not sure what happened, probably some VS updates or Windows updates, but I've tried to google everywhere and nothing had worked. Attach to process works fine as before, but this simpler way stopped doing the trick.

**Update:**

Have tried Process Monitor to figure out what is going wrong and it looks like w3wp tries to access path `MyProjectFolder\debugattach.aspx` and the result is "NAME NOT FOUND". Don't know if this is the root of the problem though.

Comment: close visual studio and open the folder where your solution is.  Try deleting the hidden folder named ,vs  open visual studio and try debugging again

Comment: This did not help unfortunately

Comment: Do you publish it to your IIS or just run it using IIS Express in project property, if you publish it, could you visit the page directly in your local browser? Can you run your app using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)"? Based on the 404 error, please make sure that the Application Pool is configured for the correct version of ASP.NET if you publish your app to IIS.

Comment: I do not publish the site, the path just points to the same location where the solution is.. Start without debugging works just fine, and the whole site works fine. I have read about the correct ASP.NET version, but that did not change in ages and I have double checked that it is set to 4. I use 4.5.2, but I doubt it should be a special choice for that?

Comment: @Ilya Chernomordik, So it was the local web app, if so, could you share a screen shot about your project properties->Web? Do you select "IIS Express" as the server? Do you enable "ASP.NET" under Debuggers?

Comment: Yes, all that is set up correctly I think. I have added a screenshot. It also did run fine before.

Comment: @Ilya Chernomordik, Not select "Local IIS", if you just select "IIS Express" in your project property, could you debug your app? At least, we could know that whether it is related to your app or the IIS configuration.

Comment: @Ilya Chernomordik, Please also remove your project from IIS manager, and then run your VS as the admin, click create virtual directory again in your project, debug your app, view the result. Or you could right click your project in IIS Manager-> Manager Application->Browser, view the result. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: 1. Tried IIS Express, looks like it runs fine there. It's very hard to know if debug actually works (hits breakpoints) because of setup, but at least it runs. 2. I have tried to delete the directory and clicked Create. It was created no problem, but the debug still gives the same message...

Comment: I have done some research and updated post with debugattach that is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help I have found the reason now! Check my answer. You have pointed me to a good direction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears that one of my colleagues has edited the `web.config` and added request filtering where he has removed the "DEBUG" verb. This disallowed debugging on F5.
After adding it (or removing request filtering) everything works fine.

P.S. A lot of other possible problems with similar error is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v)

Comment: Hi, I also have same issue, I have added the below setting in the web.config <verbs allowUnlisted="false"> <!--Allowed Verbs--> <add verb="GET" allowed="true" /> <add verb="POST" allowed="true" /> </verbs> After this setting I am getting the above error, If I remove this then it's work fine? Does someone have any Idea why this is happening? or I need to allow any specific verbs to allow debugging? I would like to keep these settings and also want debugging to be enabled.

Comment: You need to allow DEBUG verb

Comment: Solution: http://coderjony.com/blogs/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-found/

Comment: @AshishShukla this is exactly what was causing my issue too, i moved that bock to the Web.Release.config so that it will end up in the config file when we deploy to PROD. Once I removed that section from the local web.config file i was finally able to debug against my local IIS instance

Answer (score 10):

Old post but I recently had this issue and making sure that the following settings were enabled in 'Programs and Features' (Windows 10) fixed the issue for me:

[image: Programs and Features to enable]

Comment: This was my case, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In my case (Windows 10 & Visual Studio 2017) I had to install **ASP.NET 3.5** and **ASP.NET 4.7** under the Internet Information Services.

[Click here to see the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53981517/9334155)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was using the Rewrite module to redirect to https.  I was running  https://localhost/WebSiteName, but had put my machine name in the https binding in IIS Mgr, Default web Site, Bindings.  When I removed the machine name it worked.

Comment: This little nugget of wisdom saved my bacon. I hate the woeful obstructiveness of IIS configuration (actually I hate ALL Microsoft config complexity in all its forms). Instead I opted for the hack of commenting out the Rewrite module in web config. Site now works in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced the same issue in VS2013 Professional, instantly I get error 'Unable to start debugging on web server". I observed that whenever my current page is MVC view (.cshtml) file and I start debugging , the error window prompts every time. As switch the current document in my project to controller (.cs) file, and starts debugging, it works properly.
So my workaround is to debug my code I have to be on (.cs) file not on (.cshtml / web.config) file. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this problem is that you don't run visul studio **Run as administrator**.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related 405 as attached below
[image]

My issue got resolved after making my projects properties(**Web** and **Build**) as given below
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see this also
[HTTP Error 404.3-Not Found in IIS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393731/http-error-404-3-not-found-in-iis-10) as it helped me (HTTP Activation need to be enabled in Windows features)

Answer (score 0):

Im my case this error message (VS2017) was caused by the default http binding in IIS, port 80. Instead of being empty, "hostname" contained the name of my machine.

Solution:
IIS-Default site-Bindings...- port http 80 - hostname
make blank, or enter localhost