# After reinstalling iis unable to start debugging on the web server. the remote server returned an error: (404) not found.`

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

After I reinstalled IIS for some other reason, I'm now unable to debug asp.net applications in visual studio using the 'local IIS' option.
Before reinstalling IIS, everything was working fine.

This is the error I'm getting.
unable to start debugging on the web server. the remote server returned an error: (404) not found.`

I checked the web.config, debug is true

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Checked the applicationHost.config on C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
The RequestFiltering is set to Allow.

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
<sectionGroup name="security">
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

I checked the debugger log. Doesn't give any clue.
%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Visual Studio Web Debugger.log
It shows

> IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.6 - Not Found

along with some html content. That's where it mentioned about Request Filtering, but that looks good.

I'm not sure what could have ruined the debugging feature.

Comment: Have you tried running VS in administrator mode?

Comment: You may also need to reset IIS. You can do that by opening an Administrator command prompt and typing iisreset, or you can do this in IIS Manage, more info on this doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling for a while, found the solution.

1. In iis, under Default Web Site, select the application name on the left pane.
2. Double click Request Filtering on the middle pane.
3. Click on Edit Feature Settings on the right pane.
4. Check 'Allow unlisted verbs'

It worked.

Answer (score 14):

In my case (Windows 10 & Visual Studio 2017)  I had to install **ASP.NET 3.5** and **ASP.NET 4.7** under the **Internet Information Services**

Click on start menu, then Run

Write **appwiz.cpl** and click **Ok**

[image]

Click on **Turn Windows features on or off**

[image]

Go to Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features and **check** the **.NET Extensibility 3.5** and **.NET Extensibility 4.7**, then click Ok.

[image]

Close the Visual Studio, and then reopen it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for my Asp.net MVC app.