# Setting up Visual Studio to use local IIS on Windows 11 giving error that site is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019, iis-10, windows-11

I'm attempting to set up IIS on my Windows 11 computer for testing with my web applications. I can browse to the local sites without issue:

http://localhost/

http://localhost/MobileServiceForms/

I setup my project to point to this site:

[image]

This is my local IIS server:

[image]

The application folder exists. I did click the Create Virtual Directory in the project and that didn't help.

When I attempt to debug, I'm getting this message:

[image]

I checked the permissions and added the Users and myself with full control over the site and  MobileServiceForms folder:

[image]

I've tried disabling the firewall completely without any luck.

This is an Asp MVC application.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Post your `launchSettings.json` file.

Comment: Did you create a virtual directory on IIS? If you didnot create it, there's no application on IIS, so vs cannot publish to it and you cannot access it.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2022#debug-aspnet-apps

Comment: @mxmissile sorry, I didn't state what framework I am using. We are using Asp.Net MVC. I don't have a launchSettings.json in my solution.

Comment: @BruceZhang Yes I did. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer in another post, hope it helps someone else:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56344197/302613

> In order to make sure this mapping appears you need to go to control
> panel -> turn windows features on or off -> .NET Framework 4.7
> Advanced Services (or equiv .net ver) -> WCF Services -> HTTP
> Activation