# Apicontroller return HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a simple class inheriting from apicontroller.

The class code is the following:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(StatusUpdate statusUpdate)
        {
            //string url = statusUpdate.File.Url.ToString();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
```

I wrote another application to trigger the service. When I run it via visual studio I manage to get a response. However, when I deploy the above mentioned project on IIS, I get an http error 404.3 - Not found.

Any clues?

Comment: what do u mean by service? is it windows service?

Comment: Wrong url? I am just guessing as there is not enough information to diagnose what the problem could be. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alex - Apologies, I meant web service.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425442/http-error-404-3-not-found-in-iis-7-5

Comment: Igor - I'll post one. You're right, itll be clearer to explain

Comment: David - Went through that already :(