# NullReferenceException while using Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have `[Authorize]` attribute on the `HomeController`, whenever I am trying to access it, it throws a `NullReferenceException`

This is really kind of weird, because I have used `[Authorize]` many times before and it works just fine. Only difference in this case is this Application is hosted on **our own Web Server using Windows 7 & IIS 7.5**

Here is Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext
>   filterContext) +160
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>   +155
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +784976
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +335    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5()
>   +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +20
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d() +54
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +453    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371

**Edit:**

While looking into code of `AuthorizeCore` method, it seems that `AuthorizeCore` is throwing `NullReferenceException` because it gets a NULL `HttpContextBase`.

Could it be possible? Because everything else in application is working just fine, like accessing database, creating auth cookie etc.

**Edit 2:**

This happen **only** after publishing it to Web Server. While development, it works absolutely fine from Visual Studio.

Comment: I got this exception because of an invalid cookie. If you experience this as well, try to open the developer tools in your browser, go to the "Resources" tab or similar, and delete all cookies related to the site. When you reload the page, it might work. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue was even more worse `HttpContext` was not even available in Controller's and Razor views. So, I reinstall ASP.NET v4.0 using `aspnet_regiis -ir`. And then used `ASP.NET 4.0` pool which was created during registration instead of using `DefaultAppPool`.

And it started **working fine**. It also solve my another issue of overriding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` in my application web.config.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was setting `HttpContext.Current.User` to null in one of the `global.asax` application events. When I let the `User` property unchanged the error disappeared.

Comment: I was doing the same thing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make sure that the application pool your site is using has Managed Pipeline Mode = Classic.

Comment: Yes, I am using DefaultAppPool which is .NET 4, Integrated Pipeline and using Identity LocalSystem (to access SQL Server)

Comment: Looks like the problem is that httpContext is null. Try to use the Classic .NET AppPool instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515251.aspx#CLASSIC for some more details.

Comment: After changing it to Classic App Pool, it shows that DirectoryListingModule Disabled Error, because its MVC.

Comment: How did you fix this?! I'm having the same problem?! Really strange!

Comment: @Charandeep: I was having the same problem as you but finally solved it. What did it for me was that this line was missing in the web.config: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> Please see my thread on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167251/mock-presence-of-authorize-attribute

Comment: Yes, I also have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` but in `applicationHost.config` using `<location>`, because I was not able to override it in my application `web.config`.

I also stumble upon this solution, but didn't work for me. Then I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5 and reinstall ASP.NET (this time I install it from **Framework64** directory because it is a 64bit machine) and it started working.