# 404 for Custom Routes on new Machine with IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I just recently switched machines, installed the latest version of MVC and can't get my routes to work.  I'm using IIS 7.5, and I had 7 previously.  I've tried the following so far:

1) Installed the route debugger, surprisingly the 404 url's show as matching the current request.  Weird.

2) Made sure I Had UrlRoutingModule-4.0 in IIS

Are there any other config settings I may be missing?  Here are some settings I thought relevant:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="ETag" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5), which helped me realize that IIS might not have everything it needed.  I started checking boxes like it was whack-a-mole, so I'm not sure which setting did it.  My best guess would be 'Basic Authentication', since all my content is behind forms auth.

[image]