# Deployed ASP.NET MVC 4 Project Won't Run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, asp.net-mvc-4

I deployed an ASP.NET MVC 4 project to my testing server, but it does not seem to run.

Attempting to access the project URL on IIS 7 after deployment attempts to list the directory contents. Checking the folders reveals that all assemblies have been deployed. Enabling directory browsing actually lists the files in the directory and can serve static files.

It's as if my .NET 4.0 application pool is not routing any requests to the controllers.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you configure the application pool to be in Integrated Pipeline mode?

Comment: Yes. But thanks, I found the solution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Solution

Found the solution out of [sheer luck](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/app_offline-htm-gotchas-with-asp-net-mvc/), which is setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to true in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: i have wasted a whole day due to this thing... why not it is part of mvc template for deployment.

Comment: This works!!! Some other people said that this wasn't neccesary, but in my case it was

Comment: Sheesh.  I spent hours trying to get my MVC project to run.  Thank you.  For my own sanity, I would like to understand why that web.config change was necessary but the referenced 'sheer luck' solution is no longer there.  Anyone know what it was and have another link to it.

Comment: @nitewulf50 fixed link.

Comment: Thank-you for posting this.  I scoured the net trying to resolve this problem; your simple line + a restart and presto, MVC asp.net site runs.  <Big sigh of exasperated relief>

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem the other day when starting a new project on a new machine.  Then I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5) and all of my wildest dreams came true.

Comment: Thanks. ASP.NET 4 was installed properly on my end though.