# Running intranet ASP.NET MVC 3 application on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool, intranet

I'm using `Web Developer Express 2010` and `IIS 7.5 Express`. I've followed the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx but still have a problems with running my application on `IIS`.
I'm not directed to site's default view.. any view. But can list the site directory.
Application works fine when I run on `ASP.NET Development Server`.

Also I have no `Use IIS Express` option in my project `Properties` window. Is that an issue or it's normal when using `Web Developer Express`?

Thanks!

Comment: Found an answer at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5>. I didn't register ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

MVC3 requires .Net 4.0 and the tutorial isn't particularly clear about setting the .net version in the application pool.
Try setting the application pool to "ASP.NET v4.0"

Comment: I set the application pool to `ASP.NET v4.0` but didn't register ASP.NET in `IIS`.