# Install MVC website on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I use VisualStudio to build a C#-MVC3 Website and it works great.

I need to install the website on a different computer to check it. The computer has IIS7.

I tried to install (my first time... I don't really know IIS), and when I browse the site (localhost/mySite) I can see all the directories (controllers, views...) but I can't see the site itself.

I **can** see a specific file (like localhost/mySite/Content/img.jpg) but I can't see the site with the controllers (localhost/mySite, or  localhost/mySite/Home)

What to to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, install [ASP MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), then run one of the following depending on your architecture:

32bit (x86) Windows

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

64bit (x64) Windows

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

also check this thread for more info:
[ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

You could also need to recreate your application/site after these steps.

Comment: Thanks!! I went to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
and ran:
aspnet_regiis -i, then: iisreset

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try not to copy `-ir`, just type them by yourself. I don't know why, maybe I use Chinese version Windows. When I paste `-ir`, it shows some similar but incorrect characters in cmd window.

Answer (score 4):

Extension to @mikus answer (Feb 2017)

I had the exact problem described above with an **ASP.NET MVC 4.5** project on my local machine which was showing IIS 403 errors.

The fix which may be of use to others:

1). Follow mikus's answer above (I used the x64 version) in a Command Prompt window. I received a response with an 'unsupported' message, but contained a useful link:

> ...This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771..."

2). Using the step-by-step instructions given in the link to the Microsoft help page: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771. **I only had to do steps 7 and 8, which I have detailed below:**

```
- Open 'Turn Windows features on or off' [Windows key then type 'Turn Windows features on or off' and open]
- Scroll down the list and expand 'Internet Information Services'
- Within that expand 'World Wide Web Services'
- Within that expand 'Application Development Features'
- Make sure 'ASP.NET 4.6' (or 3.5 if you require that) is ticked - mine was not.
- Save and close.
```

3). Your IIS site should now work as expected - it did for me. Hit the site in the browser again to test.

Answer (score 2):

Is MVC3 installed?
It is the most common cause when publishing MVC sites to another PC

Comment: OK, I installed now from here - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211  but I still don't see the site.. (Please notice that on the other computer we don't have VisualStudio)

Answer (score 0):

Change your App Pool Managed Pipeline Mode to Integrated if you already have default settings for MVC in Global.asax.cs like

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```