# MVC2 - Running Application on II7 results in 403 forbidden

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am trying to run our MVC2 application in IIS7 using an application pool that is targeting .net 4.0 and using the Integrated pipline. If I run my application using the dev webserver (Cassini iis 6) it will work. When I try to run the application using my local iis7 webserver I just get the HTTP Error: 403.14. I have read other posts claiming that setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = true should fix the issue but it does not resolve the issue on this machine. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. This is a new machine. The following command fixed the issue.

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir