# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - MVC4 .net 4.5 bundles

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, razor, .net-4.5

I made a MVC4 application with .net 4.5 using razor engine. It works fine when run locally with visual studio.

When I deploy to IIS on windows server 2008 R2(all windows updates done), it appears my bundles do not work and the CCS is not loading. I tried viewing the site on the server, viewed source went to the bundle link for the css, and it loads some css and then there is an IIS error of:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not
>   list the contents of this directory.

What I have tried:

1) Ensured .net 4.5 is installed.
2) Added `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` to my web.config
3) Ran `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` in cmd
4) Checked that my app pool was set to Integrated Mode
5) Checked that it's set to use .net 4

Comment: What are the permissions on the folder that you are serving assets from?

Comment: @John The application pool and ISUSR both have Read permissions on the folder.

Comment: Can you show the bundling code? Have you checked if compilation debug is false with the correct target framework?

Comment: I got some problem. Any hints ? Also Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You'll find your answer here: [ASP.NET MVC framework 4.5 CSS bundles does not work on the hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081255/asp-net-mvc-framework-4-5-css-bundles-does-not-work-on-the-hosting)

The short answer is to make sure that your bundle names don't conflict with the names of paths in your sites.

Comment: Saved me a lot of time for sure... This fixed my problem, my "~/Content/Template" bundle was conflicting with my physical folder. All I needed to do was to rename the name of my bundle.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you out. This one drove me nuts for several hours one afternoon!!

Comment: Thank you. You helped me too! Btw, do you know why this occur only with the css bundles? I have the same config in js bundles and it work fine.

Answer (score 7):

This solved it for me (solution is from [MVC4 HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden/11435677#11435677))

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: While it might solve the problem, it's like killing a fly with a rocket launcher. `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` has performance impacts on your site, as all managed modules will be run for all requests, including requests for static files like images.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in your web.config you have enabled anonymous access to your "virtual" bundles paths.

For instance, if your style bundles are like "~/content/blahblah" and your javascript bundles are like "~/scripts/blahblah" you must open anonymoys access to locations "content" and "scripts" like this in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
 ...
 <location path="content">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>

 <location path="scripts">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
 ...
</configuration>
```

This way, any request to the virtual path "~/content" or "~/scripts" by any user will be granted, and the CSS and JS requests will be served.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential problem that causes the 403.14 is the global.asax and/or the web.config not being copied across in your publishing settings or deployment.

Comment: Thank you this helped me to solve the issue. Actually for me the `App_global.asax.compiled` file was missing!

Comment: This solved my problem. App_global.asax.compiled and App_global.asax.dll is missing in my bin folder. Not sure what happened. I wouldn't have checked this if not because of this comment from @Salar.