# ASP.NET MVC site getting 403 error, conventional solutions not working (so far)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC site on my home computer.  It's Windows 10 running IIS Express.  I have .NET 4.6 installed and I'm using Visual Studios 2013 Web Express to write and publish code.   When I publish my site and try to run it, I get **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**.  I've been digging around for solutions and this seems like a common error with a few easy answers.  However, I have tried them and none have worked.

Here's what I've checked so far: 
1) The application pool is .NET version 4.0, not 2.0
2) I have the following in web.config (which for most people is the fix for this issue but has no effect good or bad when I try it):

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

3) I've check and I don't have any other services with the same or similar name running.
What else could I be missing?

Comment: What is the full error message in browser, screen - could you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Sure.  Here's what comes up on the browser:
http://www.blueinferno.net/images/screenshot-of-MVC-IIS-error.jpg

Comment: It's basically acting as if it doesn't know what ASP.NET MVC is and is just trying to run what is in that directory as a regular website.

Comment: Trouble is this is a generic error, could be number of things. Couple of quick things - make sure that Global.asax & Global.asax.cs copied in correct place, can try and run `aspnet_regiis -i` - Also check routing for any obvious errors?

Comment: Lots of answers [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden), [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden), [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482637/http-error-403-14-forbidden-mvc4-net-4-5-bundles), [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323190/http-error-403-14-forbidden-iis-error-for-asp-net-mvc-4-application), [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297490/http-error-403-14-forbidden-mvc-4-with-iis-express)

Comment: & [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631211/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte) - As you can see its a common issue. One of them will have the solution, just a process of elimination I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.  It was a case of the most obvious being overlooked (because it was so obvious).  The proper .NET was installed, but not enabled.  I went in to "Turn Windows Features On or Off" and checked everything to match as follows, and it works now:

[Turn Windows Features On or Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0S2P.png)