# 403 forbidden after publishing asp.net MVC IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have been googling for hours and tried numerous solutions but nothing work. Any help is appreciated. I'm using IIS 8.5

I created a plain basic MVC application with no additional code. I published this plain default mvc template application to the server.

When I enter the address in the browser I got this error:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
Error:

When I browse to it from the server via IIS I got this error:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I tried to

- WebServer(ISS)->WebServer->Application Development add .NET
  Extensibility 3.5 add .NET Extensibility 4.5 add ASP.NET 4.5 add
  ISAPI Extensions add ISAPI Filters
- register it via command line (aspnet_regiis.exe -i)
- check network service permission
- toggle app pool credential with a specific account
- runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

... run out of ideas =(

Comment: Is the folder that IIS is pointing the folder containing `web.config`, and not the parent folder with the `.sln`?

Comment: yes, it is where it contains the web.config

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405349/193634, see if it works for you.