# run asp.net mvc5 on windows server 2012 by iis8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have asp.net mvc 5 application and i want run the app on windows server 2012 by iis 8.
I get HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I read about this problem a lot in the web.but still no solution for me.

I tried run

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

tried :

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
 </system.webServer>
```

I checked the relevant features in windows features on and off.

but still nothing,
someone can help?

Comment: Check authorization mode in web.config and  ensure that your app pool is configured properly, does pool identity has access to directory with your web app files

Comment: I don't have authorization mode in web.config,

Comment: And did you check app pool configuration?

Comment: thank about your comment. how I  need to check if the  pool identity has access to directory with the web app files?

Comment: did u see this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden]

Comment: yes. i wrote it above in my quastion

Comment: I mean there is a lot more than this: <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>  did you try everything? Did you check your pool configuration is it set for .net 2.0 or 4.0? Or maybe pool should be classic or integrated. Did you check basic settings for website and test connecction to it? Advance app pool settings and set 32 bit apps to true?