# Running ASP.NET Web API on different computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET Web API running properly on my computer `(Computer 1)`. I have deployed it on IIS using Visual Studio's publish method. It also has SQL Server connection which is configured to allow remote connections. When there is a remote connection to Web API on my computer it can answer the remote requests too.

What I need is running this Web API on a different computer `(Computer 2)` which has hardware connections. Since the other computer `(Computer 2)` is not strong enough to run Visual Studio on it I can't use Visual Studio's publish method to deploy my Web API on IIS. I've created a website on the other computer `(Computer 2)` using IIS. Then I tried to manually copying the published files on my computer `(Computer 1)` to the other computer `(Computer 2)` but IIS always gives `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`.

Is there any way to install or publish the Web API on `(Computer 1)` to `(Computer 2)`? If you have any other suggestion to run my Web API on different computer I would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show you website configuration? Does IIS have access to folders with your application?

Comment: @Kamo I think so. When I enabled Directory Browsing I can see the files in website folder. Also when I click the .html or .css files I can see the content of those files. Problem is my Web API is not working.

Comment: please share full details of error(sent request, full response, screens with both working and not working application).

Comment: @Kamo My problem is moving a working Web API on IIS to different computer. When I moved the files of this working Web API to the other computer and add them on IIS, IIS gives HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.

Comment: Check this link , this might probably help you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden

Comment: @vontarro - are both servers configured the same(in terms of IIS, ASP.NET e.g.)?

Comment: @Kamo Computer 1 is 64 bit and Computer 2 is 32 bit. That's the only difference. I tried to build my Web API choosing platform target as x64. @ jereesh I've already tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @vontarro - please share full configuration and requests data.

Comment: What's the framework version? May look into Owin and Self-Hosting the application within a windows console app or, better yet, a windows service. This keeps it pretty light-weight as well. Oh, and for what it's worth, VS doesn't have to be on the target machine. VS can publish a number of ways, including direct folder access, FTP, web deploy and others.

Comment: @BradChristie Framework version is 4.5. Now I'm trying self-host. Also I will try other publish methods. Thanks!

Comment: I simply use Publish with `File System`, then all of the API files will be output to the Target Location, and I copy these files to any IIS Website physical folder on local or on other Server, the API can work after restart that IIS Website. https://i.imgur.com/XTy2kOD.png