# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-10, iis-10

Am trying to locally host an ASP.NET MVC project on IIS 10 (windows 10 machine). But when I try to access the site I get a "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error. The contents of the Web.Config file as well as the error on the loading page are below. Is there something else am missing? Please suggest.

[image: Web.config][image: landing page]

***Update:***
Finally I figured out the issue. This is a webapi project so in the Global.asax.cs I forgot to register the route for the MVC controller which am using.

Thank you for all the suggestions.
[image: Missing route config]

Comment: check this link http://serverfault.com/questions/405395/unable-to-get-anything-except-403-from-a-net-4-5-website
and also this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden

Comment: Please paste the code into the question *as text*, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

**This check:**

- ~\Views\todoapp
- ~\Views\todoapp\index.cshtml
- ~\Controllers\todoappController.cs
- ~\Controllers\todoappController.cs `-->` `public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }`

**If the problem can not be found,Check this file:**

- ~\Views\Web.config

Comment: Also, to state the obvious (just incase), also check you are publishing your site into the correct folder that you have setup in IIS for the site.

Answer (score 1):

Just create virtual directory of project and run it on IIS.

1. Open Visual Studio `(Run as administrator)`.
2. Select your site under IIS Express Sites.
3. Right click on `Project / Site` and click on `Properties`.
4. Click on `Website` menu and `New Virtual Directory`.
5. Give Alias Name and Folder path.
6. Save The Setting and click ok.

Now run same as given alias name and path

Like, `http://localhost/ProjectName/Home/Index`

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for that is to have define

```
protected void Application_Start()
```

as an Async function.