# Resolving the 403.14 error for ASP.NET on Windows Server 2016

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-server

I am working with a brand-new Windows Server 2016 virtual machine and I deployed an ASP.NET MVC Web API application on it using Web Deploy from Visual Studio 2017. However, I found that when I browsed to the application locally, I received a page with the following error:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

After doing some research online I found that this is a common issue and that many solutions have been given. For example, see the following:

[ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

[MVC4 HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425574/mvc4-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

[HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631211/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte)

[ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

[HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden - MVC4 .net 4.5 bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482637/http-error-403-14-forbidden-mvc4-net-4-5-bundles)

[HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. Asp.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791978/http-error-403-14-forbidden-asp-net-mvc)

[HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden IIS Error for ASP.Net MVC 4 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323190/http-error-403-14-forbidden-iis-error-for-asp-net-mvc-4-application)

However, none of the solutions I tried resolved this problem on my Windows Server 2016 instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

Many people suggested running the following command to register ASP.NET on the machine:

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

It turns out that in Windows Server 2016, you need to go to the **Add Roles and Features Wizard** to do this (search for "**turn windows features on or off**" in the Windows search). In the wizard, click Next until you get to the Server Roles page. Scroll down and open the following node:

> Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Application Development

Put a checkmark next to "ASP.NET 4.6" and click Next, and follow the prompts to install it.

[image]

After installing ASP.NET 4.6 I found that the 403.14 issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I Removed **Rewrite module** from Modules and working well now.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Referencing a drive that does not exist can cause this issue! We referenced E:\Log4Net but on a new host, this drive did not exist!