# What is the Windows Server 2012 command line equivalent of `aspnet_regiis -ir`?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5, iis-8, windows-server-2012

As documented in several questions ([Alternative for the Registering ASP.NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14495429/223837); [Server 2012 IIS 8 MVC app shows default IIS home page or 403 / 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12134713/223837); [WCF on IIS8; *.svc handler mapping doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11116134/223837)), on Windows Service 2012 the `aspnet_regiis -ir` command does not work anymore, and instead produces the following output:

> This option is not supported on this version of the operating system. 
>   Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8
>   using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager
>   management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details
>   please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.

In our case, we only want to run this command to re-register ASP.NET 4.5, since some other installation un-registered it: ASP.NET 4.5 is installed already.

Using the UI (Add/Remove roles/features), inspired by the referenced posts, I found that it suffices to remove WCF's HTTP Activation feature and then add it again.  (But I needed to uninstall/reinstall a feature that happens to depend on WCF HTTP Activation...)

**Question:** How can this same thing be done through the command line on Windows Server 2012?

(I looked at this `dism.exe` thing, but it looks daunting, and `dism.exe -?` didn't help me at all.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Dism would be the best way to do this:

```
Dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45
Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45
```

Use the /all switch when enabling to enable all parent features.

Answer (score 3):

This error seems to occur when you install the .NET framework core feature which is .NET 3.5 over CLR 2.0 including HTTP activation on a Windows 2012 or 2012 R2 server which already had the .NET framework 4.5 version installed.

In our case the suggested fixes did not work.

We had a CLR 4.0 website that was showing the error:

```
Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Removing and re-adding the ASP.NET 4.5 features made no difference.

We had to remove and re-add the 3.5 features using DISM:

```
Dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation
Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation
```

You could also use PowerShell:

```
Remove-WindowsFeature -Name NET-HTTP-Activation
Add-WindowsFeature -Name NET-HTTP-Activation
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Server Manager dashboard to add/remove roles/features.
Look for IIS-->WebServer-->Application Development--> ASP.NET 4.5

Comment: He mentioned that he is able to do that already. He is asking for a command line alternative to using aspnet-regiis. This answer is irrelevant!