# 500 error after successful deployment on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I have deployed my app on appharbor but i keep getting a 500 error with the following details:

> Module: ManagedPipelineHandler Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler: System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler Error Code: 0x00000000 Requested
>
> URL:
> http://camelotfaultmanagement.apphb.com:19109/Faults/FaultManagement
>
> Physical Path:
> D:\websites\f3\33091\19109\0x0001_PublishedWebsites\CamelotFaultManagement\Faults\FaultManagement
>
> Logon Method: Anonymous
>
> Logon User: Anonymous

Here is the apps link: http://camelotfaultmanagement.apphb.com/Faults/FaultManagement

I wen't and downloaded the build results and deployed them locally on my machine's IIS to try and debug but everything went up immediately as i set the website and the app-pool to .NET 4 - integrated.

What could be causing the error ?

Comment: Far fetched... I'd be tempted to check the any connection strings and permissions to ensure they are correct for the environment.

Comment: I have deployed the same build locally so the connection string rules out, where can i check permissions in appharbor ?

Comment: I don't have personal experience with AppHarbor, so no idea on permissions. But with the huge delay before the IIS 500 message, I'd be willing to bet it's a database connection issue. You're sure the connection strings don't need to change when you run the application against a local database server vs AppHarbor's database server? Take a look at http://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer to verify that.

Comment: I actually connected to the app harbor DB from my local machine an left the same connection string that is used by app-harbor.. but i see your point with the huge delay..

Comment: Only other idea is something having to do with the pipeline management? Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/6455576/254973

Comment: Thanks but the problem was actually the connection string alias.. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!
That was the alias of the entity framework connection string.
In the AppHarbor SQL add-on i had to give the same alias as i used in my and there was a typo.