# How to deploy an asp.net mvc app to IIS 8 on azure virtual machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, webdeploy, azure-virtual-machine

Trying to deploy an asp.net mvc application with IIS 8 on azure virtual machine but Im getting the following error:

[image]

This is what ive done so far in azure Virtual machine:

1. Installed IIS
2. Installed Web deploy 3.6, web deploy for hosting server, web deploy tools 2.1, web deploy without sql bundled support
   In IIS azure Virtual machine:
3. Created a website "Nextix" in IIS
4. Disabled Default Web site in IIS
5. In my Visual Studio 2013 (asp.net mvc project), selected publish -> web deploy package
6. Copied the deployed package to the virtual machine
7. In IIS, clicked website "Nextix" and selected import application
8. Followed all instructions in Import Application Package Wizard to install Web deploy package
9. I also installed ASP.net 4 in iis by following the instruction in the link
   [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

After the steps I did, this is how my IIS application pools looks like:
[image]

And how the advance settings of my nextix website looks like:
[image]

Is there something else I need to check or do? Im still getting the above error message screen.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by following the instruction in this link: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

Comment: This is a good lead for everyone, including me. The Web Server roles in Server 2012 and 2012 R2 come with ASP.NET 3.5. You should manually include  ASP.NET 4.5 to the installation or add it later.