# HTTP Error 403.14 After installing VS 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. VS2013 previously used. 
IIS got 2 web application. First - old web forms. Second is mobile version of first web app using MVC. OS: windows 7(x64)

Web forms works as before. MVC application is not. Got HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.

Already tried all from there: [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

It is still trying to list directory and can't do it. What can go wrong with it after this installation?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Scott no. Thinking about system reinstalling. But it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Is it an MVC3 or MVC4 app?  These are not supported in VS 2015.  MVC4 support will be coming back in Update 1 later this year due to popular demand.

You can confirm you are using MVC 4 by opening packages.config and scrolling to the entry for Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.  If the version listed starts with "4", this means you are using MVC 4.

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" /> - it is MVC5