# Deployed site giving 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have recently deployed a new mvc site to replace an old one and it is giving me a 403 forbidden error (whereas the inital site worked fine).

Initially we thought this may be because the .net version on the server was not high enough for the site - the server and old site were 4.5 and the new site was built in 4.5.2.  To solve this we have upgraded the server to use the 4.6.1 framework, but still no joy.

Other solutions I have seen are to put run all managed requests in the web.config (done and no effect).

I think this may be a .net issue as if we put a flat html file in the root, it is loaded and served.  It loks like the .net is not being processed so it is hitting the root folder but as thae permissions to view directory is turned off, the 403 is thrown

Does anyone know any other causes for this issue?

Comment: are there any .htaccess file on the server?

Comment: @shiro no .htaccess or robots.txt

Comment: Does IIS have all the proper ASP.NET features installed? Also, another posible solution 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be some sort of error with the web.config - after comparing the new config with the old one and updating the parts to reflect the new version of .net, it seemed to stop throwing the 403