# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

I published my application on server. When I enter my domain i got this error:

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

What's happend?

Comment: is your iis pointing to the correct place? i once got this error when i (mistakenly) pointed to an empty folder.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden

Comment: our problem was missing global.asax file in published deploy folder

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden/41363973#41363973).

Comment: I had the same problem accessing http while issue was "Require SSL Enabled".

Answer (score 14):

Are you hosting the site on iis? if so make sure the account your website runs under has access to local file system?

Straight from msdn .....

> The Network Service account has Read and Execute permissions on the IIS server root folder by default. The IIS server root folder is named Wwwroot. This means that an ASP.NET application deployed inside the root folder already has Read and Execute permissions to its application folders. However, if your ASP.NET application needs to use files or folders in other locations, you must specifically enable access.

To provide access to an ASP.NET application running as Network Service, you must grant access to the Network Service account.

To grant read, write, and modify permissions to a specific file

- In Windows Explorer, locate and select the required file.
- Right-click the file, and then click Properties.
- In the Properties dialog box, click the Security tab.
- On the Security tab, examine the list of users. If the Network Service
- account is not listed, add it.
- In the Properties dialog box, click the Network Service user name, and in
  the Permissions for NETWORK SERVICE
  section, select the Read, Write, and
  Modify permissions.
- Click Apply, and then click OK.

Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx) for more

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the answers above, you may also get that error when you have Windows Authenticaton set and :

- IIS is pointing to an empty folder.
- You do not have a default document set.

Comment: This can happen even with anonymous access enabled and windows auth disabled if you don't have a default document set.  For instance if you run a php application and don't have index.php enabled IIS will try to serve the directory listing, which is usually disabled as well.  In that case even with anon access you will get the 403 forbidden page.  It's a real pita for those not familiar with IIS because 99% of the search results will point you to ACL settings like almagori's answer.

Comment: I love you! My solution was actually in a 2nd level folder.

Answer (score 9):

I just had this issue, it was because the IIS site was pointing at the wrong Application Pool.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue (on windows server 2003), check in the IIS console if you have allowed ASP.NET v4 service extension (under IIS / ComputerName / Web Service extensions)