# How to add mvc site to iis7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms

I have no problems with WebForms, everything i do, it work.

Now i created new test project - MVC3 app - http://prntscr.com/98ckk

and i just publish it - Visual Studio - Build - Publish - to c:\test http://prntscr.com/98cq8

Then i transferred my files  to windows server in inetpub/wwwroot/test

Then i created new website - pointing to this folder. However when i test it "ip/test" i get 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

p.s i already have IIS->Website site whitch is MVC and is working. But i dont remember what i did.

Comment: What about authentication? are you allowing anonymous access?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805311/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-asp-net-mvc

Comment: http://prntscr.com/98db4 - Auth

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

Comment: I think i solved it, ill test tomorrow with real domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Forms Authentication (or no authentication) then make sure that IIS 7 is configured to allow anonymous access and that the App Pool user has permissions to your site/folders.

If you are using Windows authentication you should disable anonymous access and turn on Windows Authentication. Then you will need to make sure that your windows accounts/groups have access.