# how to upload System.Web.MVC.dll from bin in iis7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, iis-7, bin

working with iis7.

project is in `Integrated` Pipelinemodus
Application Pool is : `DefaultAppPool`

have `System.Web.Mvc.dll, System.Web.Routing.dll, System.Web.Abstraction.dll` in bin folder of project.

i cant run aspx pages, becouse i need to configurate something in iis7 to use dll from bin folder.

please help

p.s.
seems like it has to work automatically, but i still cant run my pages

on web browser i am getting this:

```
HTTP-Fehler 403.14 - Forbidden
Der Webserver ist so konfiguriert, dass der Inhalt dieses Verzeichnisses nicht aufgelistet wird.
```

Comment: Are you getting exceptions? More info is required to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1493313.aspx) or have a look at this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

Comment: in my windows features i have everything installed for asp.net

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 is security failure response, I'd check to make sure you have a default document configured in IIS for your application path.  The 403.14 will kick in because it couldn't find a default document and directory listing is disabled.