# ASP.NET MVC and host problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, hosting

**Hi,**

I have done the following :

1. Start Visual Studio 2010
2. New Project > ASP.NET MVC
3. Default ASP.NET MVC project generated by VS2010
4. Add a couple off simple buttons on the first page
5. Start local IIS manager, Create a web application and point it to the ASP.NET MVC project
6. Set correct right on the ASP.NET MVC project folder(to the user running the thread pool in IIS7)
7. Browse site (http://localhost/MyTestSight/) and the first page is shown
8. Upload site to www.test.figurspel.net
9. Host sets the site to be runned on .NET 4.0
10. Browse www.test.figurspel.net and the site is not working?
11. The host has checked that tha Active Server Page is set to allow
12. Host has installed up to MVC 3

I could turn on the Browsable to see the file structure but this will not help to get the site running.

How do I get this asp.NET MVC web site running?

**BestRegards**

Comment: Are you sure it is IIS7? Or is it running IIS6?

Comment: When you say the site is not working what do you mean? Are you getting some sort of error message?

Comment: @jao > It is a IIS7 according to the host.

Comment: @AndyM > When we try to browse www.test.figurspel.net a security exception(403) will be thrown. If I enable directory browsing in the host controlpanel then I will see the root file structure of my site (here the site should be shown) and I can browse the folders and look at files. It seems like the ASP.NET MVC is not activated even when the host says it is? We should get the home page when browsing www.test.figurspel.net.

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong at your hosts side rather than an application problem. I'd check that the site is attached to a .NET 4 app pool running in integrated mode. It's also possible that IIS isn't being given permission to access the folder the site is deployed to or as you say that MVC isn't installed on the server. You can test for that last one by bin deploying MVC3 to your host: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Comment: It was the integration that was not set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the application pool running in integrated mode the IIS site running under that application pool?

It's my understanding that if this isn't the case, the MVC site will not run.

Alternatively, have you tried [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden/5459217#5459217)

Comment: > I have sent a mail to my host to check this. I get an 403 exception, your link talks about 404 exception?

Comment: Sorry, I was more referring to the poster's comments beneath his link.

Comment: > The problem was that integration was not set, after this fix the site works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

+1 Unicorn power HooooooO!!!!!  Also I've always when hosting a site published the project to a different folder then setup the site via IIS from that folder hope this helps.

Comment: > Im not sure what you mean? I have (as I described) tried hosting the website in a diffrent folder on my local IIS7 where it works. Its when I upload it to the host that I can´t get it running? The host account I have is not dedicated server, thay do have a control panel but I dont see that I need to set anything speciel here? The site is uploaded over ftp.

Comment: @SnowJim did you publish it to that different folder?

Comment: No? All I did was to rebuild the project, checked so it was running as expected on the local IIS7 and then uppload the files to the site. I have worked alot with regular ASP.NET and never needed to use Publish?

Comment: @SnowJim reason why I ask is because whenever I have setup a mvc project to run not just from my local machine I've published it 1st to a new folder and then told IIS to look at that folder and setup the rest from there, so you may want to try publishing the project to a new folder then uploading that new folder to that site.