# ASP pages in IIS using Localhost 401.3 Error do not have permission

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have just installed the IIS so I can view asp files in a browser but when I put the address in a browser as : http://localhost/index.asp I get an error.

The error shows this:

> HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

I really need to get this sorted out, I would highly appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: Did you look at the permissions of the file? http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;942042

Comment: No doubt the permissions on your webroot, IIRC adding IUSR account will sort the problem out.

Comment: @Phil Parsons - sorry how do I do this?

Comment: @motoxer4533 - I have opened the security tab on the file and it shows that I have full control.

Comment: Try adding the user 'Everyone', with full control

Comment: @motoxer4533 I have added the user with full control but this still shows the same error.

Comment: @motoxer4533 Seriously? - adding everyone will full control is not a fix and depending on security setup possibly downright dangerous!

Comment: @dan360 on localhost, where theres no access to the outside world, does it really matter?

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden/41363973#41363973).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

OK, working from memory here as I am not in front of a Windows machine.

If you right click on your webroot folder /inetpub/wwwroot/ or the website directory you are working on open properties and select security, I think it is, you will see the list of users with their permissions for that folder. There is a section to add new users where you can add the `IIS_IUSRS` account (search from the list of users if you need to) which will be the default user used when anonymous authentication is enabled. Give this account the relevant permissions (read, write, execute) ensuring you apply to file and subfolders. Refresh the website in IIS and you should hopefully be good to go.

Comment: +1 - I had exactly this problem and your solution worked first time. Thanks!

Comment: Just for future reference this works because the IUSR account is responsible for loading static resources. For dynamic resources you need to give permissions to whatever your application pool is running under, usually "NetworkService"

Comment: I had to both add "Forms Authentification" and give rights to "Everone " on the directory.

Comment: I had to give permission to IUSR instead of IIS_USRS

Comment: As in LawMan's answer, the user for me is IUSR. So I added IUSR as Dipendu Paul said and then it worked. Since I tried other things also it is not clear that adding permission for IUSR is everything that is necessary but at least I have an explanation for why adding permission for IUSR might be necessary. This is for a personal IIS that I set up just now in Windows 10.

Comment: For me, it worked by adding Everyone (obviously it worked) but more specifically it needed IUSR

Answer (score 92):

My issue was around the identity used in the app pool.  I changed the site's Authentication to "Application pool identity" as well as giving the directory the appropriate permissions.

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer! Thanks a lot! I wish I would give you some money!

Comment: Thanks! But why?! The default config worked for a while for me, until I rebooted my computer and then I had to apply your fix.

Answer (score 4):

I had one folder not working (extracted from a zip file which came from an email from some kind of MS Sharepointy thing. Or something). The files were all marked with Windows Explorer -> Right Click -> Properties -> Advanced -> Encrypt contents to secure data. Unticking cured it.

Comment: not obvious at all, but this is what did it for me.

Comment: I also found that when I publish/deployed these files, they got deployed as encrypted. Even after I'd unencrypted them.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had created an application in IIS 7 on Windows 7 using "Add Application" on the Default Web Site. I had to add the "users" account from the local machine and that got rid of the permissions error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me and what I needed to do was apparently add a web.config file. Doesn't matter that it was just a PHP site, and that "Everyone" had full control. Until there was a basic Web.config - NO DICE!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your site in IIS, go to Authentication under IIS on your right hand side and double click it then change the site's Authentication to "Application pool identity” and make sure that you give the directory (where published files are) the appropriate permissions.
And your restart your IIS and your error is gone.

Answer (score -4):

Here, the set up process is explained in detail. You can follow the steps.

http://coldfusion-tip.blogspot.com/2013/10/you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this.html