# how to run asp program in windows 7

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to run an asp program in my windows 7 system but it is showing an error that 
"HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server."
Can you please tell me step by step about running the program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232922/asp-pages-in-iis-using-localhost-401-3-error-do-not-have-permission

Comment: yes i have installed IIS

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is not intended for use as a server so it has some unforgiving security rules. Even with Windows Server out of the box, you need to open up your firewall, as the default is intended to be secure until you are ready to go live.

In IIS check that your site is public.