# deploying mvc 4 asp.net with iis in windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

i created a mvc4 asp.net app using the default template within visual studio 2012. i can build and run the app with no problem.

now im trying to host this in my computer (windows 7 ultimate). i turned on iis in my machine, and  i did this :

- open iis manager
- right click sites and "Add Web Site"
- set site name to "site1"
- set physical path to "C:\Users\DaFriskyMonkey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\mvc4app"
- click "Ok"
- then i go to "Application Pools" and change".Net Framework version" to "v4.0"

so when i navigate to "localhost" i got this : **HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.**

when i go to "edit permissions" for the "mvc4app" folder "IIS_IUSRS" has "read" permission.

what should i do to make things work properly.

thanks you all.

Comment: this link give you simple solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232922/asp-pages-in-iis-using-localhost-401-3-error-do-not-have-permission

Comment: I suggest you copy the security configuration from the default IIS folder (c:\inetput\wwwroot\WateverWebsite) to your mvc4app folder.

Comment: i cant answer my own question because of reputation issues (im to fresh).

but i found an easy answer for my own question.

i create a *default web site* in iis manager.
trough visual studio 2012 i *publish* my app in this *default web site*. i cant believe this was so easy.

hope this can help someone someday.