# how to publish web service in v.s 2012 on local machine

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web, publish

*1- I've publish web service in v.s.2012 and automatically creates the .zip file.
2- but in IIS , after clicking 'browse' option the i got "HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized. You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server."*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the IUSR account has enough permission on the wwwroot folder. It is the default user for anonymous authentication. (Rightclick on wwwroot -> properties -> security -> select IUSR)

[image: screenshoot wwwroot -> properties]

**EDIT:**
Also found this post with the same Problem, also explaining the above posible solution and others, maybe this helps:
[ASP pages in IIS using Localhost 401.3 Error do not have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232922/asp-pages-in-iis-using-localhost-401-3-error-do-not-have-permission)

Comment: I already add IUSER and allow all permssion to IUSER and IIS_IUSER, but error is still the same.