# Unauthorized error on control F5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have hosted single html page in `IIS`. When I open it using url (`http:myipaddress/test.html`) it works fine but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> it gives me error.

> **HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized**
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of
>   the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for
>   this resource on the Web server.

also it doesn't open in other PCs in domain server. I have given read/write permission to few users in network and added `IIS_IUSRS` user as well.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was around the identity used in the app pool. I changed the site's Authentication to "Application pool identity" as well as giving the directory the appropriate permissions.

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22251963/3664659)