# IIS Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I am facing a problem with IIS and ASP.net. I reinstalled the IIS because it wasn't showing the "Default Website" and after that I reinstalled ASP. Now I am facing the error you see below. I should mention that it was working before the IIS reinstallation and the reason I reinstalled it was because I needed to edit the bindings and there was no "Default Website".

[image]

Comment: Check if the IIS_IUSRS group still has permission to read that directory. It's possible the group has been regenerated with a new SID.

Comment: @Rup could you tell me where to check that?

Comment: @Rup Under authorization rules, "All users" are listed for "Allow".

Comment: Oh - that's probably OK then. It might be worth adding IIS_IUSRS explicitly just in case - I half remember that the app pool users don't count as regular Authenticated Users.

Comment: @Rup did it, still the same result

Comment: :-/ Sorry. There's a few more ideas in this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6685720/243245

Comment: @Rup I tried everything. When I try to use a method in a controller, it says that the resource could not be found and it actually tries to open the file. I sounds as if ASP is not really at work, any thoughts?

Comment: Tried everything, reinstalled IIS, still nothing.

Comment: You did run aspnet_regiis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days, I finally managed to solve this. What I did to fix it was to make sure that `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` is present in `Web.config`. This fixed the issue.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I would like to talk to you about something VERY important. Can you send an email to me at sachinkainth[at]hotmail.com please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that you're using MVC.  You'll need to ensure your routing is set up right and is actually executing.

[ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

[ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: well, some things from the first link helped me and I fixed it :) Thanks