# Silverlight 403.14 Error

Tags: c#, silverlight, http, iis, iis-7

My silverlight application test page will no longer load and I've been given a 403.14 error.  The start up project is set to the web, and I have a data model attached to it.  I've researched all the solutions to do with the IIS Manager and nothing seems to fix the issue.  I even started a test project and added the data model and it worked just fine.  Is it a problem with the IIS, or is it something in my project settings?? Thanks.

Comment: Many solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden.