# Error 401 for my ASP.NET app on IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, http-status-code-401

I've just wrote a legacy app on IIS 6.0 (.NET 1.0, don't even ask why!). One of the requirements is to have "Integrated Windows Authentication" disabled on the Virtual directory.

```
http://localhost/test.html
```

When I disable that, I get a error 401.1 on the IIS root's test.html, which consists of "Hello World"

> You are not authorized to view this page You do not have permission to
>
> ### view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
>
> Please try the following:
>
> •Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able
>   to view this directory or page. •Click the Refresh button to try again
>   with different credentials. HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is
>   denied due to invalid credentials. Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> ---

When IWM is enabled, the website works like a gem.

Does anyone know what is the root cause? This doesn't appear to be an issue with my app since even the default test.html fails with authentication

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/035dcfd0-9a36-4788-b3b6-91dc6a9d9936.mspx?mfr=true perhaps?

Comment: Anonymous access was already enabled by default

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden/41363973#41363973).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved with removing Guest and Anonymous restriction from the local security policy

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to set the correct folder permissions for the 'Anonymous' user on the folder you are accessing.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f594e137-e2da-4b22-ab58-f8edba938802.mspx?mfr=true

**edit:** this is the more relevant link:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9ded7af2-fcb7-4ed2-b007-e19f971f6e13.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: IUSR_CATXXXXXX was already added to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot with Read & Execute, List Folder Contents and Read permissions.

test.html sits under C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test.html

Comment: Silly question but still: have you verified which user is configured as anonymous? And Anonymous Access is enabled?

Comment: yes I have verified the user. It is a member of Guest group and it has the permissions to the root folder

Anonymous Access is also checked..