# New ASP.NET MVC 4 Intranet Template project response 403 Forbidden?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

First time creating an ASP.NET MVC4 Intranet template. As soon as it finishes being created, I run the application and all I get is a 403 Forbidden response. No matter what I browse to, no errors, nothing, just a blank page.

What in the world is going on?

Following along on [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-intranet-application-in-mvc-4/), it should run out of the box.

**Edit**

Some other weird behavior

1. It works on my other computer.
2. I can't step into any debug break points either. I tried setting a break point in the Index action of the HomeController and it never breaks into the program.

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in the response headers?

Comment: Status code 403 Forbidden

Comment: did you search around? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11029588/365968

Comment: are you using IIS Express, Web Development Server, or native IIS? 
In my opinion, The problem is not with the code, but with the server that hosts the code.

Comment: I'm just trying to run it in visual studio, so it's the built-in IIS Express. I agree, it's something with the server. I just have no idea what it is. It works on my other laptop just fine...

Comment: Hum, this is a wild guess. Probably, you didn't run the Visual Studio as Administrator or you create the new project in the drive or folder that couldn't be access by the account the VS or IIS Express used.

So, perhaps you compare the locations on which you create the new project in your laptop that is working or not as well as the user account used.