# Why spring-saml-extension and adfs 2.0 return a 403 error?

Tags: adfs2.0, spring-saml

I don't know what am I missing about configuring spring-saml-extension and adfs. I did everything as mentioned [in this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html), but IIS returns me a `403 forbidden error` with this message:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Is there anything else I need to do on IIS?

Comment: You may want to start with going through ADFS's logs.

Comment: Hi Vladimír,

I just enabled ADFS's log as shows this [link] (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1407.how-to-enable-debug-logging-for-active-directory-federation-services-2-0-ad-fs-2-0.aspx).

However it is not logging the requests yet.

Something I noticed is that   [initiatedsignon.asp](https://adfsserver/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx) returns the same response.


Something about permissions is missing.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden/41363973#41363973).

Answer (score 1):

Well,

after hours researching about this I found what the problem was.

There is an ISAPI filter on

> IIS -> Default Web Site

that was redirecting request to another place.

I got this by enabling httpErrors to DetailedMode:

`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" /section:httpErrors /errorMode:Detailed`

Then, when I entered to `/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx`, ISS throwed this screen: [Http Error 403.18 - Forbidden](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aphdrtvdxtk5qsi/http%20error%20403.18%20%20forbidden.png?dl=0)

For more information about this, I would recomenend to see [throbleshoot ISS errors like a pro](http://mvolo.com/troubleshoot-iis7-errors-like-a-pro/)

So, what I did was to remove that filter at

> IIS -> Default Web Site -> ISAPI Filters

and it finally worked :)

Thanks @admdrew and @Vladimir for your help.

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm glad you found a solution and thank you for sharing it. Welcome to StackOverflow!