# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I created an MVC5 site and deployed to my dev machine IIS.

However I can't get past this error when I browse to the URL.

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

I tried implementing the settings in this thread, but I still get the same error.
[ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-)

My setup:
Publish Method: File System

From IIS 7.5 I added a new Web Site and pointed to my published folder location.

 I created a new app pool and set it to 4.0 and managed pipeline is integrated(also tried classic).

What am I missing?

Comment: Can You add more screenshot of Your IIS Manager? and your IIS, what you've been activated at Control Panel "Programs and Features" application?

Comment: If the error still occurs, may I team viewer your PC? (If my connection available)

Comment: I can't for that would be a security violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open CMD,

If you are in 32 bit OS, Run :

`C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

If you are in 64 bit OS, Run :

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same error and fixed error as following:

1) Open command prompt (cmd) and write command as 'appwiz.cpl' 
2) Open the menu "Turn Windows features on or off" 
3) Internet Information Services/Application Development Features 
4) And checked ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.6

[IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx1cx.jpg)

Hope will work for you