# Configure my server to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I have uploaded my asp.net MVC project to my server (hostek) using Visual Studio FTP.

Do I need to configure anything else? Because when I try to run the website, it displays:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.


Most likely causes:

    A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden seems like a duplicate question, but I'm not familiar with hostek.

Comment: I already tried to add the <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> and the other steps in that question

Comment: Check your `BundleConfig` and `WebConfig` to see do you need to change any thing on server on not.

Comment: Our configured 2008 server just started giving the exact same error after installing update KB4034664. The runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests did not work for me either.