# 403.13 when using action link to go to {controller}/Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I am getting the following error when debugging my header links.

[image: Error Message]

I have tried recreating my Index.cshtml (Empty and with Razor/HTML) and my ServicesController.
If I browse to Services/Index explicitly then the page loads up correctly.

IE: *localhost:58069/Services/* does not work but *localhost:58069/Services/Index* does

My other controllers are working correctly using the same structure and ActionLink helper.

**Not working code:**

```
public class ServicesController : Controller
{
    // GET: Services
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Action Link HTML Helper for Services/Index**

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Services", "Index", "Services")</li>
```

**Working Code**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home/Index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Working Helper**

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Welcome", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

**Route Config**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Tried the following SO solutions:

[ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

[image]

Comment: You said when you navigate to Service/Index it loads, yet your controller is Services so the default folder structure should be Views/Services/Index.cshtml not Views/Service/Index.cshtml.

Comment: I fixed the spelling mistakes in my explanations. 

The View is in View/Services/Index.cshtml I'll add a photo as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the Services folder (below Scripts folder) you have in your project. When hosting in IIS, you should not have a file or folder with the same name as your ASP.NET route.

Ways to solve this:

- [`routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) will let ASP.NET handle all the routing
- Rename your Services folder or controller
- Move Services to a separate library and remove the folder from the web project

I'd recommend the latter option as settings `RouteExistingFiles` to true would need additional research to double-check you're not opening any security holes and it cleans up your web project (a little bit of separation never hurts).

Comment: Winner Winner Chicken Dinner, it was a namespace issue on my internal services... Where my namespace matched my controller name. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: I ran into the same issue when creating a new environment and using IIS8.  IIS7 worked fine with the services folder in place and not setting RouteExistingFiles.